# PHP and HTML checking if username is in database

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to solve a problem pertaining to PHP.
So far I have created an html login form login.html and a PHP file login-insert.php. I'm having trouble detecting if the username already exists in the database created using phpmyadmin. I'm very new to coding in PHP so any help is appreciated

Please refer to link for PHP and html code https://liveweave.com/rAE7Cy

Comment: Does this "form" have an action to post/get the data to `login-insert.php`? If `login-insert.php` exists could you share that code here?

Comment: There is no form inside your database, see how to make a form here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: For your php script, you have to do it yourself,  learn how to use php to connect to your database here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp and perform select query here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: @tshimkus look i have share my login-insert.php code link in the description please refer that.

Comment: Can anyone here help me out??

Comment: Is your most recent version linked above? I can't tell as there are many different versions in the comments

Answer (score 1):

Step 1
    create a file `config.php`

```
<?php
   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost:3036');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'rootpassword'); //modify it as per your password
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'database'); //modify it as per your databse
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

Step 2 
    create another file `login.php`

```
<?php
   include("config.php");
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['uname']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['psw']); 

      $sql = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['active'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

      if($count == 1) {
         session_register("username");
         $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

         header("location: home.php");
      }else {
         $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks mate for help but still something missing. Line 13 "$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);" and line 16 "$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);" error occured. the error is 1. "Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\copy\login-insert.php on line 13" and "Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\copy\login-insert.php on line 16".

Comment: hey can anyone here help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your file name with the extension login.php instead of login.html and then send the variable value through ajax in the same page

```
<?php

    // starting the session
    session_start();

    // checking if username and password entered of not
    if(isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['userpass'])){
        $server = 'server_name';
        $user = 'server_username';
        $pass = 'server_password';
        $db = 'database_name';

        $conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

        $userid = base64_encode($_POST['userid']);
        $userpass = base64_encode($_POST['userpass']);
        $useremail = $_POST['userid'];

        $q = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE UserID='$userid' AND UserPWD='$userpass'";  // Fetching data from table
        $d = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($d) == 1){
            while ($t = mysqli_fetch_assoc($d)) {
                $_SESSION['login_status'] = 1; // Creating A login status variable in case of logout make this variable value 0
                echo '1';
            }
        }else{
            echo '2';
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }else{  //if username and password not entered
        ?>
            <input type="text" class="userid" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="password" class="userpass" placeholder="Password">
            <a href="#" class="login_btn ">login</a>

            <script>

                $('.login_btn').on('click',function(){
                    var userid = $('.userid').val();
                    var userpass = $('.userpass').val();
                    if(userid != ""){
                        if(userpass != ""){
                            $.ajax({
                                type:'post',
                                data:{
                                    userid:userid,
                                    userpass:userpass,
                                },
                                url:'login.php',  // Sending variable to same page

                                success:function(e){
                                    if(e == 1){ // Userid and password is correct
                                        window.location = 'index.php';
                                    }else if(e == 2){
                                        alert("Invalid Username and password");
                                    }else{
                                        console.log(e);
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        }else{
                            alert("Password Required");
                        }
                    }else{
                        alert("Username Required");
                    }
                })
            </script>
        <?php        
    }

?>
```

Comment: if you can explain than i will

Comment: https://liveweave.com/LKpy8a plese check this link i have done this so far.

Comment: it seems like you have just started html css

Comment: I have already  told you in the above code if there is any confusion that you can ask specifically

Comment: According to your code i have done some modifications as per my database names and table names but still missing something. https://liveweave.com/tAOyYg please check my modified code this code contain both html and php files.

Comment: still not working mate sorry to say this but i really don't know now how to solve this problem only one you are the hope

Comment: what error is it showing ?? press  f12 key of your keyboard after clicking on login button it will open console panel of browser and then you will be able to see the response from your server

Comment: $('.login_btn').on('click',function(){  on this line this error occured Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined